# h:messages does not display the message

Tags: jsf

I am trying to display a success message in XHTML which was set in Bean. However no message is being displayed. I tried looking at so many places but could not figure out the issue. The following is my code snippet.

ManagedBean code :

```
try {
        // Service call to register individual
        String text = "Congratulations !!!Registration Successful.";
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,text, text);
        // The component id is null, so this message is considered as a view message
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        return "registerSuccess";
    } catch (EmailException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());               
        return "registerFailure";
    }
```

Submit Page :

```
<h:form>
    <!--The form fields-->
    <h:commandButton value="Confirm" action="#{registerBean.register}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

registerSuccess.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/xhtml/common/seeLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="mainContent">
        <f:view transient="true">
            <h:form id="registerSuccessFormId" prependId="false">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Registration Success</h3>
                <label class="info-text">
                    <h:messages globalOnly="true" infoClass="info-text-info" warnClass="info-text-warn" errorClass="info-text-error"></h:messages>                          
                </label>
            </h:form>
      </f:view>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: try debugging with firebug. enable the network tab and check what's in the response page

Comment: According http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html the method `.addMessage()` does "Append a FacesMessage to the set of messages associated with the specified client identifier, if clientId is not null.". According your code, you pass a null value to the client id. It could be one reason for your trouble

Comment: @reporter passing `null` as id means that the `FacesMessage` will be handled automatically by `<h:messages>`.

Comment: Code contains much irrelevant noise and is not in MCVE flavor and the submit button is missing. Are you submitting it by ajax? Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi BalusC, I am able to reach the bean method with minimum required code. So felt it might not have any significance. I edited the question to reduce the noise and added only relevant information

Comment: Small progress in the issue. When I returned to the same page from where I am submitting, then the messages are shown. I mean in bean method return ""; But when I returned to a new success page like return "registerSuccess"; I am not able to see the message.The bean is at Request scope